# Excel VBA error on searching and paste script

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making the excel VBA script that will copy and paste value on the first sheet ̣̣(Input) to the data storage sheet (DATA). If the update flag on J4 cells on Input sheet turned to 1, it will search the cell of DATA sheet that contain value on K4 cells of Input sheet and paste value to it. Half of the objectives have been completed, but when writing the script to find and paste value to the cells that have value of K4 cells it called

> error 1004: Application-defined of object-defined error

on the PasteSpecial row of the script.

My script is here:

```
Sub add_data()
Dim DATA As Worksheet
Dim Input As Worksheet
Dim otk As Range
Set D = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
Set I = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
L = 1
While L = 1
    If I.Range("J4").Value = 0 Then
        I.Range("K4:UX4").copy
        lastrow = D.Range("B1")
        D.Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                    Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                                                    SkipBlanks:=False
        L = 0
    Else

        With D.Range("A1:A10000")
            Set otk = .Find(I.Range("K4").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not otk Is Nothing Then
                I.Range("J4").Value = 0
            Else
                I.Range("K4:UX4").copy
                D.Range(otk).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                                 Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                                                                 SkipBlanks:=False
                L = 0
            End If
        End With
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Range otk needs to be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
Set otk = .Find(I.Range("K4").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not otk Is Nothing Then
    ' runs when otk is something
    I.Range("J4").Value = 0
Else
    ' runs when otk is nothing
    I.Range("K4:UX4").copy
    D.Range(otk).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                     Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                                                     SkipBlanks:=False
    L = 0
End If
```

Otherwise `otk` is nothing when you go into the `Else` part.
Also `otk` is a range object and not an address so you need to use it as `otk.PasteSpecial`.

So you need to change `If Not otk Is Nothing Then` into `If otk Is Nothing Then`

```
Set otk = .Find(I.Range("K4").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If otk Is Nothing Then
    ' runs when otk is nothing
    I.Range("J4").Value = 0
Else
    ' runs when otk is something
    I.Range("K4:UX4").copy
    otk.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                     Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                     SkipBlanks:=False
    L = 0
End If
```

Alternatively you can switch what is in the `Else` and in the `If` part.

```
Set otk = .Find(I.Range("K4").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not otk Is Nothing Then
    ' runs when otk is something
    I.Range("K4:UX4").copy
    otk.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                     Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
                     SkipBlanks:=False
    L = 0
Else
    ' runs when otk is nothing
    I.Range("J4").Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: Isn't otk a range  ? so `D.Range(otk).PasteSpecial` should be `otk.PasteSpecial`

Comment: @CDP1802 missed that one, nicely spotted! I changed it.